# Moving multiple files to multiple directories by percents

Tags: linux, files, mv

I have a directory with `100,000` files. These are audio files which I need to move to three different directories, `train` , `dev` and `test`. In the order of `80%` , `10%` and `10%` respectively.

```
mv `ls | head -500` ./subfolder1/
```

This moves files if we know the number by default but not by percent of total no of files. I wonder if there's a neater way to split dir to three.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to use output of `ls` as an input.

You can achieve what you want with a little script:

```
#! /bin/sh
# file counter 
cnt=0

# for each file (replace *.* by *.mp3 to restrict to some files)
for i in *.*
do 
    # create a number for 0 to 9 from the counter
    a=$(( cnt%10 ))

    # for 8 files on 10,
    if [ $a -lt 8 ]
    then
        # move file to train folder (think to remove `echo`)
        echo mv "$i" train/

    # for one file on 10 (a is 8)
    elif [ $a -lt 9 ]
    then
        # move file to dev folder (think to remove `echo`)
        echo mv "$i" dev/

    # for one file on 10 (a is 9)
    else
        # move file to test folder (think to remove `echo`)
        echo mv "$i" test/
    fi 
    # and update the counter
    cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
```

Comment: for any no of files does it move 80% to train, 10 % to dev and test ?

Comment: @OBX Yes, unless you have too few files (like less than 25)

Comment: cool , let me try it out,

Answer (score 0):

Using a shell like `bash`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get all names.
# This assumes that *.mp3 matches only the things that we'd like to move.
names=( *.mp3 )

# Create our destination directories.
mkdir train dev test

# Calculate some numbers...

n=${#names[@]}           # 100% of the files

# Six files at least are needed...
# (or one of the directories will be empty)
if [ "$n" -lt 6 ]; then
    printf 'Only %d files\n' "$n"
    exit 1
fi

n80=$(( (80*n)/100  ))   # 80% of the files
n10=$(( (n - n80)/2 ))   # 10% of the files

# Move the files...

mv "${names[@]:0:n80}"   train # Move the 80%
mv "${names[@]:n80:n10}" dev   # Move the 10%
mv "${names[@]:n80+n10}" test  # Move the rest
```

This reads the names of the files that we'd like to move into an array called `names`.  It is assumed that the pattern `*.mp3` used will match *only* and *all* the names that we are interested in (modify this pattern to suit your needs).

The 80% and 10% lengths of this array is then calculated.

The moving of the files are done using array slices (in `bash`).  A slice `${arr[@]:offset:length}` is the slice from the zero-based offset `offset` of length `length`.  If the `length` argument is missing (as in the last call to `mv`), the slice runs to the end of the array.

The number of files that end up in each directory will obviously be a bit approximate due to the fact that we're not ready to split files in two (integer arithmetics). The `test` directory is likely to get one more file than what `dev` gets if the number of files is not evenly divisible.

This also relies on the filenames being short enough that 80% of the files can be moved in a single operation.  If that's not the case, you would have to change the last three lines (the `mv` lines) into

```sh
for name in "${names[@]:0:n80}"; do
    mv "$name" train
done
for name in "${names[@]:n80:n10}"; do
    mv "$name" dev
done
for name in "${names[@]:n80+n10}"; do
    mv "$name" test
done
```